# Spring MVC testing: How do I check if a model attribute does not exist?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, junit

I’m using Spring 3.2.11.RELEASE.  I’m using the new 3.2 mock MVC framework for unit testing, and normally I can check for model attributes using something like the following …

```
private MockMvc mockMvc;
…

@Test
public final void test()
{
…
    mockMvc.perform(get(“/mypath”)
                    .param("userId", customerId))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andExpect(model().attribute(“attr1”, “value”))
                    .andExpect(view().name(“my view"));
```

but how would I adjust the above to verify that the attribute “attr1” was NOT included in my model?

Comment: there's also a .containsAttribute() method on Model

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the model attributes are a held in a map you could check that the value of the attribute is null (Assuming that null isn't a valid value for the attribute).

```
.andExpect(model().attribute("attr1", nullValue());
```

where `nullValue()` is `org.hamcrest.Matchers.nullValue`.

Answer (score 7):

Even easier approach than Mark's:

```
.andExpect(model().attributeDoesNotExist("attr"))
```

Comment: Thanks Saraph. Note this requires spring-test-3.2.4 or higher.